# Why is my spark web-interface not active?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose, airflow

I have created a `docker compose-file` in where I defined `Spark`, `Airflow`, `Postgres` and `Flower`. After I do a `docker-compose up -d` in my `cmd` I get the following output:

```
[+] Running 11/11
 - Network airflow_spark_default                Created                                                            0.8s
 - Container airflow_spark-redis-1              Started                                                            3.7s
 - Container airflow_spark-spark-worker-1       Started                                                            2.9s
 - Container airflow_spark-postgres-1           Started                                                            3.8s
 - Container airflow_spark-spark-1              Started                                                            4.1s
 - Container airflow_spark-airflow-init-1       Started                                                            9.5s
 - Container airflow_spark-airflow-triggerer-1  Started                                                           26.7s
 - Container airflow_spark-flower-1             Started                                                           27.4s
 - Container airflow_spark-airflow-worker-1     Started                                                           26.4s
 - Container airflow_spark-airflow-scheduler-1  Started                                                           26.4s
 - Container airflow_spark-airflow-webserver-1  Started                                                           27.0s
```

Everything seems running correctly. So when I surf to `localhost:5555` I get the `UI` of `Flower`, when I surf to `localhost:8080` I get the `UI` of `Airflow`. But when I surf to `localhost:4141` I get a `This page is not working` in Google Chrome. What is wrong with Spark?

This is how the `Spark` service is defined in my `docker-compose file`:

```
  #Spark 
  spark:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    ports:
      - '4141:4141'
    volumes:
      - ./spark-apps:/opt/spark-apps
  spark-worker:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
```